# How do I automatically adopt the MenuItemIcon as a button header when I select it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button that opens a context menu when clicked:

```
<Button  x:Name="AlterMenuButton" Click="AlterMenuButton_Click" Content="{Binding DataContext.filterforID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="7"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 0" BorderBrush="Black" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="-90,2,0,5">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="contextmenuAge">
            <MenuItem Header="endswith" Click="MenuItem_Click">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <TextBlock Text="=" FontSize="16" Margin="5 -3 0 0" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="startswith" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>                                       
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

When I click on the MenuItem with the MenuItem.Icon, I want the icon of this MenuItem to be placed on the button as content.

Before I click on the MenuItem with the icon:
[image: Before]

When I click on the MenuItem:
[image: After]

How can I apply the the Icon of the MenuItem by clicking on it on the Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    TextBlock textBlock = menuItem.Icon as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        //clone the TextBlock if you don't want to remove it from the MenuItem
        AlterMenuButton.Content = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = textBlock.Text,
            FontSize = textBlock.FontSize,
            Margin = textBlock.Margin,
            FontWeight = textBlock.FontWeight
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great, but if I now have several buttons so not only "AlterMenuButton" how do I have to change it with the Sender?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. If you post the link to it here, I'll try to help you out.